# How to aviod running the command "source devel/setup.bash"

Tags: ros, source, devel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I've built a catkin package which has a main node and links against a repository. My problem is that everytime I need to use the package I have to run  "source devel/setup.bash" before running the command 'rosrun'. Otherwise, I receive an error.Is there any way to solve this problem and avoid to run this command everytime?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200174/how-to-aviod-running-the-command-%22source-devel/setup.bash%22/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you add  `source ~/ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash` to your bashrc it will automatically source it as soon as you open the terminal.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-29**:
Thanks. My problem was solved.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-29**:
Note: if you have multiple workspaces, adding a `source ..` line to your `.bashrc` is actually a pita.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-29**:
@gvdhoorn. By a pita you mean is not good? if so, What do you suggest?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-30**:
Yes, a 'pita' is not good :).

If you have multiple catkin workspaces (*not* multiple packages), you could perhaps do something with suitably configured terminals (ie: have each terminal source a different `setup.bash`). Then start the appropriate terminal. Personally, I just source my workspaces.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-30**:
Thanks, I get it. So far I have edited bashrc file because sometimes things get complicated and I forget some details so by editing bash file I reduce the probability of receiving errors.